# Array of separators for strtok() function

Tags: c

I want to divide my text into words. Separator is any symbol except latin letters.

Here i have loop, filling my separators array:

```
for(i = 0; i <= 127; i ++) {
    if(!isalpha(i)) {
        separators = (char*) realloc(separators, (length + 1) * sizeof(char));
        separators[length] = i;
        length ++;
    }
}
```

Then i use it here:

```
char text[] = "hello world!";
char** words = NULL;
char* p = strtok(text, separators);
int cnt = 0;

while(p != NULL) {
    words = (char**) realloc(words, (cnt + 1) * sizeof(char*));
    words[cnt] = strdup(p);
    cnt ++;
    p = strtok(NULL, separators);
}

for(i = 0; i < pnt; i ++) {
    printf(" - %d %s\n", i + 1, words[i]);
}
```

As a result a have:

```
-1 hello world!
```

If separators array is replaced by " " is works well.
What's the problem with array?

Comment: Please, don't cast the `void *` returned by `malloc`, `calloc` and `realloc` if you're writing C. a void pointer is all you'll ever need

Comment: By the way, many of the non-alphabetic "characters" in the ASCII table you will most likely never get (like most below 32).

Answer (score 3):

The first value of `i` in your loop, 0, is not alpha; so a 0 will be stored as the very first byte in the separator array.

`strtok()` expects to receive the separator list as a *string*, and strings in C are terminated by a zero. So `strtok()` receives a sequence beginning with a terminator, and it thinks is an empty list, with no separators at all.

You can start the array from 1 to get rid of that interfering zero:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 127; i ++) {
  if(!isalpha(i)) {
      separators = (char*) realloc(separators, (length + 1) * sizeof(char));
      separators[length] = i;
      length ++;
  }
}

// then you also need to terminate it, otherwise strtok() will continue reading
// past the end of the array, with unpredictable (but very likely undesirable) results.

separators[length] = 0x0;
```

You might also want instead to allocate the string only once (you waste some space, but save some time);

```
#define MAX_SEPARATORS 128

separators = (char*) malloc(separators, MAX_SEPARATORS * sizeof(char));
for (i = 1; i < MAX_SEPARATORS; i++) {
  if (!isalpha(i)) {
      separators[length++] = i;
  }
}
separators[length] = 0x0;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that the `strtok` wants the separators as a *string*, complete with a string terminator character (`'\0'`). Unfortunately you don't have that terminator in the `separators` "string", so `strtok` will read that one beyond what you have allocated leading to *undefined behavior*.

Comment: It is defined behaviour; the first character is the terminating null.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ah, a more subtler bug that it was too early for me to find. :)